# joining 3 or more table and sum the fields

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird

I would like to join 3 tables.

The result is one of the field - SUM from the other table like this image, please help

[image: Joining table and SUM field]

Comment: Have you tried anything?? Or just want us to write your code and do your homework?

Comment: I already work with colasce (), but I need to add more condition inside that colasce so I can have the result like attached, if you may help?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: Bad way of asking the question. I would suggest you try googling, try out some approaches and then post here what you tried, what worked and what didn't.

Comment: Add the query you've tried so far

Comment: If you value your sanity, consider not storing 'id', 'tr', or 'w'.

Comment: Request for free programming service

Comment: So, is this MySQL or Firebird ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to join `tblwork` as you can get all required fields from other 2 tables.

Following query should work:

```
select t1.nmstudent,
           sum(case when t2.idwork = 'w001' then t2.trprice else 0 end) as w001,
           sum(case when t2.idwork = 'w002' then t2.trprice else 0 end) as w002,
           sum(case when t2.idwork = 'w003' then t2.trprice else 0 end) as w003,
           sum(case when t2.idwork = 'w004' then t2.trprice else 0 end) as w004
    from tblstudent t1
    inner join tblTrans t2
    on t1.idstudent = t2.idstudent
    group by t1.idstudent;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes, it works, but the nmStudent at t1 that doesnt contain any value doesnt appears

Comment: So the whole row for that name doesn't appear at all?